# How to add my array data as key, value to use in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am creating a button in WordPress editor and every thing working fine by now, but I have some dynamic data in my array and want to use that array. Scenario is some thing like this, I want to give that array's key as drop down name, while I'll be using that array's value as value for that drop down. 
Here is my code for that button so far which working fine,

```
editor.windowManager.open( {
    title: 'Insert header tag',
    body: [{
      type: 'textbox',
      name: 'title',
      label: 'Your title'
    },
    {
      type: 'textbox',
      name: 'id',
      label: 'Header anchor'
    },
    {
      type: 'listbox',
      name: 'level',
      label: 'Header level',
      'values': [
        /*{text: '&lt;h3&gt;', value: '3'},
        {text: '&lt;h4&gt;', value: '4'},
        {text: '&lt;h5&gt;', value: '5'},
        {text: '&lt;h6&gt;', value: '6'}*/

          jQuery.each(ajaxResult, function(obj, values) {
              console.log('its from that key');
              {text: obj, value: values},

          })

      ]
    }],
    onsubmit: function( e ) {
      editor.insertContent( '&lt;h' + e.data.level + ' id="' + e.data.id + '"&gt;' + e.data.title + '&lt;/h' + e.data.level + '&gt;');
    }
  });
}
```

I want to use this array code as my list but it says in console that unexpected : while its fine I think. Here is my each function to print that array's values

```
jQuery.each(ajaxResult, function(obj, values) 
    console.log('its from that key');
    {text: obj, value: values},
})
```

It should just print its key in place of obj and its value in place of values ... that's what it intended but its giving me that error. Can any one guide me where am I going wrong ??? Please any one help me out on this ... Here is my my array data which i printed in console.

```
{"another":"another","Uncategorized":"uncategorized"}
```

I just want "another" as key and its value as value in my above button click function. But its not working any one to guide me please ???

**Note:** `ajaxResult` is my array's name which I am using.

**Note:** This commented code which is static works fine but I want it to replace with my dynamic data which is in array.

```
/*{text: '&lt;h3&gt;', value: '3'},
  {text: '&lt;h4&gt;', value: '4'},
  {text: '&lt;h5&gt;', value: '5'},
  {text: '&lt;h6&gt;', value: '6'}*/
```

Comment: I know what you problem is, but show me how `ajaxResult` looks so I can write up an answer for you.

Comment: I am getting an array from my php script the array looks like this Array
(
    [another] => another
    [Uncategorized] => uncategorized
)

Comment: then I have created an array in my jquery like this var ajaxResult=[]; and I am pushing that response from php to my this jquery array like this ajaxResult.push(response);

Comment: then all my array data is inside my jquery array now and I want to put that array data inside that commented code's place .... to print my drop down with dynamic data returned from my php script .... hope its very clear by now ... please help me out its really killing my whole day now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you're trying to run `each` inside an array declaration. That will not work. 
If your `ajaxResult` looks like `{"another":"another","Uncategorized":"uncategorized"}`, all you have to do is

```
var values=[];
jQuery.each(ajaxResult, function(text, value) 
{
    values.push({text: text, value: value})
})
```

then, simply assign `values` to the `'values'` property, like so

```
'values': values
```

Comment: got it, but once  i used this one it throws this error now. wp-tinymce.php?c=1&ver=4401-20160726:12 Uncaught TypeError: (r[n] || n).replace is not a function(…)

Comment: its not working bro ... but it looks like WE are so close now :(

Comment: That error is in the place, which seems to be unrelated to this question.

Comment: place ??? i could not get that ... can you elaborate what that place mean ?

Comment: what that means please ? I Have not such knowledge ... plzz do it working for me ... my job is in danger then :(